# How to create a conditional class binding in vue 3 and add more class when condition fullfilled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am new to Vue js 3. How to create a conditional class binding in Vue 3. I want it like this. If `router.path != '/'` then add class `'nav-bar-two'` otherwise keep blank. in laravel, it's easy to add a class with an if else condition. But in Vue js, it's different. What to do? i am using vue3, vue-router, laravel 9

```
<div 
class = "main-nav" 
v-bind:class="$router.path !== '/' ? 'nav-bar-two' : '' ">

....some other HTML code.....

</div>
```

My Final Result should be like this
if I am not in `index` path like `"/"` then the class should be `class="main-nav nav-bar-two"` and if I am in `index` path `"/"` then the class should be `class="main-nav"`

Answer (score 4):

Vue3 has awesome [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)

```html
<div class="main-nav" :class="{ 'nav-bar-two': ($route.name !== 'Home') }">
    ....some other HTML code.....
</div>
```

Comment: There's no $router.path at least

Comment: Thank you . But it's not working. I tried this method earlier also. But not working. But I don't know why. Every path get this. one other thing is I'm using vue router. as <router-link> to navigate

Comment: :class="{ 'nav-bar-two': ($route.name !== 'Home') }"
This way it's done. and working. Thanks Antek Pietryga

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer. Final answer is

```
<div class="main-nav" :class="{ 'nav-bar-two': ($route.name !== 'Home') }">
    ....some other HTML code.....
</div>
```

Description:
Dont know why $router.path is not working but should work. $route.name is working.

Comment: Looks qui a lot like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74970773/8816585

Comment: It's a copy of another answer to the same question.

Comment: What's the point of that?